# Why did 'decrepit' replace 'decrepid'

Tags: etymology

According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decrepid#English), 'decrepid' was a common alternative spelling of 'decrepit', declining in usage and becoming uncommon around 1930s.

Why did 'decrepit' replace 'decrepid'? I can't think of any other adjectives with a 'pit' suffix, while I can think of plenty with the 'pid' suffix - e.g. insipid, rapid, vapid, etc etc.

I'm also curious as to whether 'decrepid' was the original word, or whether 'decrepit' was. The wiktionary entry suggests it's the latter, but it's not completely clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to have been 4 stages in the "decrepid/decrepit" war.

In A, decrepit was probably still seen as a French word used by authors with a "good education", i.e. the majority of authors. However, the word had started to leak into the more popular vocabulary, and -

(i) with the paucity of English adjectives ending in "it" and far more adjectives ending in "ed"

(ii) people who had heard it spoken but not seen it written -

a compromise of "id" was made to suit pronunciation.

In B, there was a surge in frequency of "decrepid/decrepit" as, more people found a use for it, but, absent a reliable orthography, many still persisted in the phonetic, anglicised version that seemed more natural.

We can see how the change in spelling developed in this from the OED:

> decrepute, decreaped, 1500s–1600s decrepite, decrepet, 1600s decrepate, 1600s–1800s decrepid, 1700s decripid, decriped, decripped.

All of which gives an insight into the variety of accents in English around that time.

In C, we see final and finer details of English orthography being hammered out amidst the growth in the number of publications.

D is the era of broadly standardised orthography in which, although there were some alternative spellings permitted, standardisation was the norm.

[image: Frequency of spelling graph.]

Answer (score 4):

Decrepit is the original spelling from French, decrepid appeared later, around 1600c, probably as a misspelling, but its usage gradually declined from [the 19th century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decrepit%2C%20decrepid&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) in favour of the original spelling.

***[Decrepit](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=decrepid%20)***:

> “broken down in health, weakened, especially by age," mid-15c., from Old French decrepit (15c., Modern French décrépit), from Latin decrepitus "very old, infirm" (of old men and old animals). (Etymonline)

***[Decrepid](https://www.wordsense.eu/decrepid/)***:

> Obsolete spelling of decrepit (17th-20th c.)